# Upper bound for the infimum of $(K-x)^2 + (T/x)^2$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I have a function

$$f(x)=(K-x)^2 + \left( \frac{T}{x} \right)^2$$

where $K$ and $T$ are positive constants and $x>0$.

The function $f$ (hopefully) has an infimum, in terms of $K$ and $T$.

I want to put an upper bound for this infimum, only as a function of $T$. And this function should go to zero, as $T$ goes to zero.

**in other words,** I want to show that

$$\lim_{T \to 0^+} \sup_{K \in \mathbb R^+} \inf_{x \in \mathbb R^+} f(x) =0$$

Actually, I don't know whether it is true or not. Can you please help me for this problem?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt{T}+K$. Then $(K-x)^2=T$ and $\left(\frac{T}{x}\right)^2\lt T$. So the minimum is $\le 2T$ for any $K$.  The supremum over all positive $K$ of the minima is indeed exactly $2T$.

Comment: Oh, sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. The choice of $x=K+\sqrt{T}$ was inspired by the easily shown fact that the minimum of $x^2+\frac{T^2}{x^2}$ is reached at $x=\sqrt{T}$.